# add all the hours in a column vba excel with for each and if

Tags: vba, excel

I want to add all the hours in a column that have such a date (strDateForm = strDate) and strFunction = "1" but my function takes only the last data in the column instead of adding all the corresponding data. 
Can someone help me please.

```
Public Sub CalculHeuresTotalChauffeur()

Dim tblPagination As ListObject
Set tblPagination = Worksheets("Pagination").ListObjects.Item    ("tblPagination")

Dim heureTotale As Single
Dim sommeTotale As Single

If StrComp(tbxTempsChauffeur, "") = 0 Then tbxTempsChauffeur = "0"
If StrComp(tbxTempsChef, "") = 0 Then tbxTempsChef = "0"
If StrComp(tbxTempsDemenageur, "") = 0 Then tbxTempsDemenageur = "0"
If StrComp(tbxTempsCoordonnateur, "") = 0 Then tbxTempsCoordonnateur = "0"

For Each srcRow In tblPagination.ListRows

strDate = srcRow.Range.Cells(1, 3)
strDateFormulaire = dtpDate.Value
strNoFonction = srcRow.Range.Cells(1, 21)


If strDateFormulaire = strDate And strNoFonction = "1" Then

heureTotale = CSng(srcRow.Range.Cells(1, 13).Value)

End If

Next
sommeTotale = heureTotale + CSng(tbxTempsChauffeur.Value)

tbxHeuresChauffeur.Value = sommeTotale

End Sub
```

Comment: Try having your addition for a total happen inside of the loop, so that your total hours can keep adding up, rather than happening for one cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
heureTotale = CSng(srcRow.Range.Cells(1, 13).Value)
```

You should do

```
heureTotale = heureTotale + CSng(srcRow.Range.Cells(1, 13).Value)
```